# Need help using mod_rewrite to redirect some URL's based on query string

Tags: wordpress, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, redirect

I have a WordPress site and need to redirect some URLs based on a query string.

The link is `/?product_brand=brandname`

I need to redirect them all to `/?product_bisbrand=brandname`

Can someone point me in the right direction, please?

Answer (score 1):

Try putting this somewhere appropriate in the htaccess file in your document root:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} (.*)product_brand=([^&]+)&?(.*)
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /$1?%1product_bisbrand=%2&%3 [R=301,L]
```